# How to connect an android application to raspberry pi?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, iot

I am trying to develop an android application in which when I click a simple button in the app an led must glow which will be connected to a breadboard. I am a beginner when it comes to raspberry pi and IOT related things. I already tried android things but I couldn't reach to any solution. I have already flashed the rasbian os in my raspberry pi. Can anyone suggest to me that where should I start regarding this? What I am trying to ask is simple "How can I connect with the peripherals from an android application"? It would be really helpful if someone gave a step by step guide on where to start regarding this problem.

Comment: you need to start web/grpc/whatever server at RPI and communicate with it. simplest way to prototype such thing would be to use either [python](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2018/04/how-to-control-raspberry-pi-gpio-via-http-web-server/) or [node.js](https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/iot-controlled-web-server-using-nodejs-webserver-and-raspberry-pi) or [php](https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/control-led-with-raspberry-pi-webserver-using-apache)

Comment: `trying to develop an android application in which when I click a simple button in the app an led must glow which will be connected to a breadboard` Such has been published many times on internet by many magazines. In fact it is a basic task.

Comment: You could use [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) to connect to any Linux distribution in RPi from Android, works from WiFi or USB.

Comment: Depends on the peripherals

Answer (score 0):

You may use network or bluetooth to connect.

You can try to connect your Raspberry PI to your router(either wired-connection or WIFI is ok) and then let your phone join the LAN. Then start a socket server or a http server on you PI and your android phone can send a packet or a request to PI after the button clicked.

Comment: Do you have any tutorial related to this? Or a website link from where i can easily learn?

Comment: An example :https://towardsdatascience.com/python-webserver-with-flask-and-raspberry-pi-398423cc6f5d (just alter the web with an app)